# Unable to display conda environment in status bar

Tags: linux, terminal, tmux

I am a newbie of Tmux and I am now configuring the status bar in Tmux. I want my tmux status bar can show the current Conda environment like Powerlevel10K.  I tried  `set -g status-right "conda: #{CONDA_DEFAULT_ENV} | %a %h-%d %H:%M "` but it failed.  The tmux status bar shows nothing in the name of current conda env.
So the current right bottom corner of my tmux is like

[image]

but what I actually want is something like

```
conda: base | Wed Sep-06 23:18
```

Comment: Is the `#` sign intended or should it be `$`?

Comment: You are right, if I want to return the current conda env, what I should do is `#{echo $CONDA_DEFALUT_ENV}`, though this method does not work. After spending several hours I finally come up with the solution and I will post it later

Answer (score 0):

## Resolution of TMUX showing/updating conda environment

Finally I came up with the solution of showing or updating conda environment in the Tmux status bar. I have tried to use

```
set -g status-right "conda: #(echo $CONDA_DEFAULT_ENV)
```

but it doesn't work. It seems that Tmux does not know the `$CONDA_DEFAULT_ENV`. I have try similar method on `$PATH` and it works fine. Finally, I asked GPT4 to how to correctly show conda env name and it suggests to add following code in `~/.zshrc`

```
# Update TMUX environment variable
# Add conda.sh to PATH
source /opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/etc/profile.d/conda.sh

# Update TMUX_CONDA_ENV every time a new prompt is generated
precmd() {
  if [[ -n $TMUX && -n $CONDA_DEFAULT_ENV ]]; then
    tmux setenv -g TMUX_CONDA_ENV "$CONDA_DEFAULT_ENV"
  else
    tmux setenv -gu TMUX_CONDA_ENV
  fi
}
```

The following is GPT4 explanation on the code snippet

```
We might need to take a different approach. Let's try using the 

PROMPT_COMMAND environment variable, which holds a command to be executed 

before each command prompt. We'll update the TMUX_CONDA_ENV variable 

inside the PROMPT_COMMAND so that it changes every time a new prompt is 

generated.
```

Now in `tmux.conf` we need to modify the original line to

```
set -g status-right "Conda: #{?TMUX_CONDA_ENV,#{TMUX_CONDA_ENV},base}"
```

and it works well now. It not only shows the correct conda env name, but also update the conda env name once we switch to other environment.